# Displaying two dynamically added elements in different rows

Tags: javascript, html, joomla

I've an `HTML` page like following:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <div id="emaildiv" class="main" style="width:150px;height:80px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to add a DIV with a `TEXT` and `BUTTON` in to it dynamically. All these are made by using the following javascript.

```
function newEmailForContact() {
    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('emaildiv');
    var newEmailDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newEmailDiv.setAttribute('id','newEmailDiv');
    newEmailDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display:table;');

    var newEmail = document.createElement('INPUT');
    newEmail.setAttribute('type','text');
    newEmail.setAttribute('name','newEmail');
    newEmail.setAttribute('class', 'textfield_addemail');
    newEmail.setAttribute('id','newEmail');

    var addEmailBtn = document.createElement('INPUT');
    addEmailBtn.setAttribute('type','button');
    addEmailBtn.setAttribute('name','addEmail');
    addEmailBtn.setAttribute('id','addEmail');
    addEmailBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Add');
    newEmailDiv.appendChild(newEmail);
    newEmailDiv.appendChild(addEmailBtn);

    parentDiv.appendChild(newEmailDiv);
}
```

But the `TEXT` and Button are displayed in two different rows.

EDIT :-
CSS class :-

```
.textfield_addemail    {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999999;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333333;
    width: 120px;
    height: 15px;
    }
```

I want to display both in same row. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your initial `<div>` isn't wide enough at 150px, just increase the size a bit, like this:

```
<div id="emaildiv" class="main" style="width:250px;height:80px;"></div>​
```

[You can see a working/updated example with *only* this change here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rCayC/1/).

Comment: I've made changes to the width as you said, but still its displaying in two different rows. There are lots of space available to fit the button.

Comment: @Joe - Given your example that should work...do you have *additional* CSS rules that apply to these elements?

Comment: Try to apply a smaller width to your input field: newEmail.setAttribute('size','8');

Comment: Yes I'm using a CSS class. I've updated it in the Question. Please check it

Comment: @Joe - Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/SxkEg/ Does this not work either? I tested in Chrome/FF/IE8 here, are you using something else?  If the example works there's still something outside your question's code/styles affecting this.

Comment: @nick-craver - I'm using FF2 and I'm locked to it. I cant use anything else.

Comment: @Joe - Is the example page I linked in the last comment doing the same thing?

Comment: @nick-craver - I'm getting a right pane and a main area of a web page. In main area, I can see two sections "JavaScript" and "result". But they don't have anything in it to display.

Comment: @Joe - That shouldn't be the case, any addons running?

Comment: @nick-craver - I got a new machine with FF latest on it. :) . I've tested the above links  from it. and both of them are working correctly. But when I used it with my web page. Same problem repeats. :(

Comment: @nick-craver - I forgot to mentioned that its a joomla page where I'm using these sripts.

Comment: @nick-craver - At last I got it working in FF3. As you mentioned in your first reply it was the width caused the problem. But I don't know why it have problem with FF2. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the

```
newEmailDiv.setAttribute('style', 'display:table;');
```

Then your `span` will be displayed as *inline* and your button should appear next to it